# Listen to events inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So I have a main page (a) and a preview page (b) embedded into the main page via an iframe. The page (b) triggers a special event:

```
$(document).trigger('preview.compiled');
```

Now I want the main page (a) to listen to this event and do something then:

```
$('iframe').contents().on('preview.compiled', function() {
    console.log('Success');
});
```

However, the code above doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You might consider using postMessage instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Are you including jQuery on both pages? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman, yes. Also no errors. When I try to listen to the event from the (b) page with, I get a success message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

jQuery's `trigger()` only triggers the callbacks that were added through `.on()` of its own instance. So the jQuery within your iframe is only going to trigger the callbacks that were set using that instance, not any set through the jQuery instance of your main page.

You could instead call `dispatchEvent()` passing in your own event object

```
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('preview.compiled'));
```

Or can instead use [window.onMessage / window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or [Broadcast Channel api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) with modern browsers

window.onMessage / window.postMessage, [check browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Browser_compatibility)

```
//in main window
window.addEventListener('message',function(message){
  if(message.data.type=="preview.compiled"){
    //do something
  }
});

//in iframe
parent.postMessage({
  type:"preview.compiled",
  other:"other data to pass"
},"url of main window");
```

Broadcast Channel API onMessage/postMessage, [check browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API#Browser_compatibility)

```
//Main window
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('preview:compiled');
bc.onmessage = function(message){
   console.log(message.data);
};

//iframe
var bc = new BroadcastChannel('preview:compiled');
bc.postMessage('Some data');
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I am trying to make it work with postMessage however keep getting the data parameter empty. The iframe seems to be setup correctly (incl. the url part). Will try to find out what's wrong.

Comment: What are you passing it?

Comment: OK, I found the problem. The main page $(window) should not be a jQuery object, but window.addEventListener('message; ... );

Comment: Ah, fixed the answer to reflect that

Answer (score -2):

Try parent.$('body').trigger('preview.compiled');